# Have an Excel Auto Scroll Macro; is there a way to put a timer on it?

Tags: vba, excel

So here's what I have for the auto scroll macro:

```
Sub Macro12()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To 23 Step 2
        Cells(i, 1).Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll down:=2
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")) 'Wait two seconds before 
        continuing.
        If i = lastRow - 2 Or i = lastRow - 1 Then
            i = 0
            Cells(1, 1).Select
        End If
    Next i
    Debug.Print (i)
End Sub
```

The issue with this is that it eventually freezes and crashes Excel. What I'm trying to find is a timer code that will tell it to run the macro every 60 - 90 seconds. IE: run Macro12, then don't for 90 seconds, run it again, rinse repeat.

How would I go about this?

EDIT:

This code works:

```
Sub ReRunMacro()
    Dim xMin As String
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To 13 Step 2
        Cells(i, 1).Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll down:=2
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        If i = lastRow - 2 Or i = lastRow - 1 Then
            i = 0
            Cells(1, 1).Select
        End If
    Next i
    Debug.Print (i)

    xMin = GetSetting(AppName:="Kutools", Section:="Macro", Key:="min", Default:="")
    If (xMin = "") Or (xMin = "False") Then
        xMin = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please input the interval time you need to repeat the Macro", Title:="Kutools for Excel", Type:=2)
        SaveSetting "Kutools", "Macro", "min", xMin
    End If

    If (xMin <> "") And (xMin <> False) Then
        Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("0:" + xMin + ":0"), "ReRunMacro"
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

But instead of looping back to the first row (or A1) it just keeps going. Would a simple  `Range("A1").Select` do the trick to looping back up before running the auto scroll again?

Comment: Have you looked up how to schedule a macro?

Comment: A little, but I'm not entirely sure if that's what I want or if it's possible to run it all in one macro. I'd prefer the latter, but if scheduling a macro is the only way, then I'd go that route.

Comment: Presumably you want it start from where it left off the previous time? Can I ask what is your objective?

Comment: So we have a sheet of tables that display out in the shop. If we have more than four tables, the sheet is cut off. The objective is to have the sheet autoscroll (which it currently does) to display all the tables, then loop back to the top. I was hoping that a timer could keep excel from crashing since the code I have is currently an infinite loop.

Comment: Also, the idea is for this to be run via google docs so I don't think running a VBS timer would work.